Examples of unconventional mathematical notations that seem nonsensical at first but are rigorously justified with the right definitions.
I’ve encountered several instances where mathematical notation might appear "odd" or "weird" at first glance, but after a deeper look, it becomes clear that with appropriate definitions, it is perfectly formal. For example, one of my colleagues shared this way of deriving the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ using an operator-theoretic approach:
$$e^x=\int e^x \text{ , using } "\int" \text{ as an operator.}\\e^x-\int e^x=0\implies (1-\int)[e^x]=0\implies e^x=(1-\int)^{-1}[0]$$
We can expand $(1-\int)^{-1}$ as $1+(\int)+(\int)^2+\dots$ , thus:
$$e^x=(1+(\int)+(\int)^2+\dots)[0]$$
Then , he argued that while the first term is $0$ the terms after are not since it is not $\int 0dx$ but rather $\int 0 $ with the integral operator applied to $0$ and another way to see this is asking "what functions derivative is $0$? It is a constant." So $\int 0=c$ . From the starting conditions we can evaluate that $c=1$ and therefore $$e^x=0+1+\frac {x^2 }{2!}+\dots$$He said that he was not the one that came up with this but with proper definitions it is a valid proof.
While I'm not yet sure how to formally justify it myself, I was fascinated by how abstract operators and non-standard notations can be used in a formal way.
Q: Are there other examples in mathematics where unconventional or irregular notation may at first seem useless, but can be strictly justified by appropriate definitions or schemes?

Note: I know this is an unusual question and will probably get downvoted a lot because it might not be clear enough what I'm asking. I would appreciate any suggestions to improve the post or if my question is not suited for this site I'd be happy to delete it if you can point me to some other resources that I can use. Thanks in advance for any answers or pointers!
EDIT:

By non-standard notations, I mean mathematical symbols or operations that initially appear to lack clear meaning or structure, but are well-defined and useful.
I am looking for unconventional notations and methods, not just proofs that initially appear illogical or unorthodox due to unfamiliar notation or structure, but can be made rigorous once the underlying definitions are understood.

I understand that the question is broad but I am also expecting a variety of answers. I want to make it clear that I am seeking to expand my understanding in this concept that really excites me and not just solve a particular problem. Any answer provided will be very much appreciated from the simplest to the most complex.

You might not have given the best example of what you're asking for. Would umbral calculus be any good?

@J.G. Thanks for the suggestion! Umbral calculus is a great example of what I meant. I will try to edit my original post to clarify more exactly what I am asking.

you can use some similar hand-waving to make the process of solving a linear, non-homogeneous ODE like $D[y,y',y'',...] = f(x)$, by treating it like a polynomial, which I think is cute.

You could improve ease in validating your example if you dropped using indefinite integrals, and instead used a definite integral with a variable upper limit. However the real issue is justifying $(1-\int)^{-1} = 1 + \int +\int^2 +\dots$. To justify this, you need $\int^n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ and integration in general is not known for such behavior. It only works here because $n!$ grows faster than $x^n$ for a fixed $x$.
